# printf of a char in C with absurd values

Tags: c, printf, ascii

I searched a lot on the internet trying to find the reason for the line below to work normally in C:

```
printf("%c", -999);
```

When the complete ASCII table goes from 0 to 255 or from -127 to 127 in C (char type documentation in C).
I would like to understand why it prints a symbol that theoretically does not exist with this decimal code. I know that it ends up repeating the symbols that actually exist in the table when I put absurd values, 99999, -88225 etc. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

I expected it not to show the symbol when it was a decimal value that doesn't exist in the table, but it ends up showing normally.

Comment: it's interpreted as a char at some point so re-framed into 0-255 value and printed.

Comment: Hi, do you have an idea of how this reframing is done? I tested it here with the % operator and it didn't work

Comment: [Undefined behavior is undefined](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9): "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Citing https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf: "The argument [of type int] is first converted to unsigned char." Try `(unsigned int)-999 & 0xFF = 0x19 = 25`

Comment: For signed types "reframing" is undefined, for unsigned types it keeps only the lower byte, so is frequently equivalent to  `printf("%c", -999 & 0xFF );`. I'm not sure if here we are in the case **undefined behavior** with unpredictable effects including can display some char, or is the char displayed is unpredictable (I think we are in the 2nd case).

Comment: @dalfaB: The term you are looking for is not [undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), but rather [implementation-defined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.1). According to [§6.3.1.3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3), the behavior in this case is implementation-defined.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The correct type for `%c` is `int`, and the type of `-999` is `int`, so that rule is irrelevant. Whether the value is a problem is a separate matter not addressed by that rule about type.

Comment: it is just the value there, at the first byte... 0x19 0xfc 0xff 0xff a.k.a the int representation for -999

Answer (score 3):

It happens because of modular arithmetic.

When describing the `%c` conversion specification, the standard [says](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> [...] the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char` [...]

Now how is an `int` is converted to `unsigned char`? This is described [here](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2):

> the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type

This is an overly wordy description of modular arithmetic. The standard could have said instead "the new value is the original value *modulo* one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type.

So in order to find out what will be printed when you `printf ("%c", -999)`, you can compute (-999) mod 256 and look it up in the character table (if your `unsigned char` ranges from 0 to 255, which is true on most usual platforms).

Note that the modulo operation is the same as `%` for *positive* integers, but not the same for negative ones. `(-1) % 256` is `-1` rather than `255`. So if the result is negative, add 256.

Comment: I guess they wrote it like that to avoid having to define which variant of *modulo* they meant!

Comment: Right. Considering the positive 999, we have 999 % 256 = 243. I understood, because when I printf("%c", 999) or printf("%c", 243), I get the same result.
Taking advantage of your knowledge on the subject, can you tell me why gcc or the language itself does not follow the extended table in order (https://marquesfernandes.com/desenvolvimento/codigo-ascii-tabela-ascii-completa/)?
Well, the 243 corresponds to the "ó" according to the link above, but when I printf("%c", 243), the 3/4 symbol appears (code 190 in the table)

Comment: @IgorCastilho If you hear someone talking about the "extended ASCII table", stop listening to them right away, they don't know what they are talking about. There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". There are different *character encodings* in use (look up this term) and you need to know which one your system uses.

Comment: it is just the value there, at the first byte... 0x19 0xfc 0xff 0xff a.k.a the int representation for -999

Comment: @arfneto You can view it this way too because modulo 2^n in 2s complement happens to work this way.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit sure, but I believe it is a lot simpler just to see that the specifier `%c` in `pritnf` is taking just the value of the first byte of the `int`, as expected, as `unsigned char`. See the code I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

No need to search in internet: use your compiler.

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    union
    {
        int           value;
        unsigned char byte[4];
    } x;
    x.value = -999;
    printf(
        "value %d (decimal) is [ 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X ]\n",
        x.value, x.byte[0], x.byte[1], x.byte[2],
        x.byte[3]);
    printf("[%c]\n", x.value);
    char  buffer[80] = {0};
    char* p          = (char*)&buffer;
    int   dump       = sprintf(p, "%c", x.value);
    printf(
        "sprintf returned %d value is %d [0x%X]\n", dump,
        buffer[0], buffer[0]);
    return 0;
};
```

Here is the output from CL 19.36, gcc 13 get the same output (the actual symbol displayed on screen can be other).

```
value -999 (decimal) is [ 0x19 0xFC 0xFF 0xFF ]
[↓]
sprintf returned 1 value is 25 [0x19]
```

And it is an unsigned char with value 0x19 anyway.

Not an absurd value